# Longest Path in a grid graph

Tags: graph-theory

Question: What is the longest possible path in a grid graph? Prove it.

I know that there is a formula that says: the maximum length of a path in a graph with n vertices is n-1.
I thought to prove it using the pigeon hole principle. But I'm not sure this is the right approach.

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  Start from vertex $a$ and look at a minimal path to vertex $b$.  If that path has length $n$ then some vertex must be visited twice by it.

Comment: Thanks, very easy to understand it intuitively. Do you think it's a valid proof?

Comment: Sure.  It's a (simple) application of the pigeon hole principle...$n$ pigeons with only $n-1$ holes.